# Default to filter by Most Recent on Facebook profile

Tags: facebook

When I visit Facebook, the initial page is always Top News. Is there a way to make it display Most Recent as the default sort filter instead?

Even better if I can have it default to a specific filter in Most Recent.

Comment: or write yourself a nice greasemonkey script ;) if you want help with that, I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible at the moment, but you can bookmark this URL which will always take you to Most Recent:

http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=lf

Another bet would be to use a browser add-on that can achieve this:

> [Better Facebook](http://betterfacebook.net/) is a FREE browser
>   extension that improves Facebook by
>   adding lots of great enhancements and
>   functionality!
>
> [Facebook "Most recent" by default](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-most-recent-by-defaul/)
>   is a plugin which automatically
>   switches to "Most recent" instead of
>   "Top news" when you first enter
>   Facebook.